# Firebase libraries must use the exact version error

Tags: android, firebase

I want to use google cloud messaging for push notification to android application. I read bellow document and set firebase to my application. My gradle build successfully but in `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'` part, I get following error:

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 17.1.0, 16.2.0, 16.1.1, 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.0.1. Examples include com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0 and com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

App gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "notificationtest.com.test.notification"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

You have added 2 different versions of firebase library.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
```

Please change it to same version i.e, 15.0.2
I am using this version only and did not face a problem until now. If you want you can probably use 16.0.1 for messaging also. There might be a possibility that google has not released version 17 for firebase-core.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but when i changed firebase-core verstion to 17.1.0, i get failed to resolve:com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0 and i read https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message document, in there use version 16.

Comment: It's allowed in newer versions of Firebase libraries (since version 15 of all of them) to have different versions.

Comment: @DougStevenson any supporting document for that? I don't think you can use one library on version 15 and another on version 16.

Comment: I'm the one who wrote the announcement blog:  https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

Comment: Also take a look at the Firebase docs.  How could all the versions be so different?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries

Comment: @manishpoddar  I set firebase-core and firebase-messaging to version 15.0.2 but i again get error in firebase-core,  error is firebase-iid version 15.1.0 and play-sevice-measurement-base  vesion 15.0.2 is not same

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry did not know you are developer advocate for firebase. Well then why is he not able to build successfully?

Fahim is this your complete build.gradle?

Comment: If I knew, I'd answer.  Sorry.  I don't have time to dig into it, but the fact of the matter is that the versioning system can still have problems, and you can see that if you do some searches looking for similar error messages.